# how to access the request attribute, on an included JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, include

So I am currently creating a header that will be included on all my JSP for this dynamic web application. This header needs a important variable from the request attribute. I am sending the request to the main page.

```
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/homepage.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

homepage.jsp currently has an include of this header.jsp.

```
<jsp:include page="/header.jsp" />
```

I know it is getting the header asset, as I'm arriving on the page but getting a null pointer trying to reach the request attribute out of the request.

```
MembershipBean membership = new MembershipBean();
    membership = (MembershipBean)request.getAttribute("membership");
```

How do I access the request attribute of the main page I am sending this too?

Comment: before forwarding add membership object to request attribute

Comment: I was doing that but I'm glad you said something as I had membershipData as the request attribute, and membership was what I was looking for in the header.... feeling a bit dense this morning. Thank you

Comment: glad it helped somehow..

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the request attribute membership when I was sending over membershipData.